# How to create a public method in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using this opensource core, want to add my own functionality.

Here is the service:

```
"use strict";
define([
  'mediastream/webrtc'
  ], function(WebRTC) {
    return function() {
      this.testcall = function() {
        console.log(1);
    }
  };
});
```

here is how i call it:

```
 "use strict";
  define(['underscore', 'text!partials/buddylist.html'], function(_, template) {

    // buddyList
    return ["buddyList", "api", "webrtc", "contacts", "sourceDistribution", function(buddyList, api, webrtc, contacts, sourceDistribution) {


  //console.log("buddyList directive");

  var controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

...

        $scope.doViewBroadcast = function(id) {
          sourceDistribution.testcall();
        };
```

So How does one call the `testcall()` function?

Comment: No ideas ?      .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
"use strict";
define([
  'mediastream/webrtc'
], function(WebRTC) {

  var Testi = function(api) {
    var broadCastTypes = ["call", "video"];
  }

  Testi.prototype.doCall = function(api) {
    console.log(1);
  }

  return ["api", function(api) {
    return new Testi(api);
  }];
});
```

call with:  `sourceDistribution.doCall(id);`